# how to do a join operation in HBase?

Tags: java, join, hbase

As far as i know, NOSql databases typically doesn't support the join operation, but I need to do this in my program I am writing. Is there any way or technique to join query responses in HBase? (Query Language: Java API)

Thank you in advance

Comment: you may want to redesign your database structure as there is nothing like a  "moderate NoSQL".

Comment: Are you absolutely certain about this? If you are, I wouldn't spend more time finding a solution.

Comment: HBase doesn't support Joins - if you supply more details on what exactly you are trying to do someone may come with an alternate design

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz: I posted this question in another form,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767188/joining-two-resultsets-from-hbase-in-java

Comment: If you really need to do a Join in Hbase, you could use Apache Phoenix which acts as a SQL layer on top of Hbase https://phoenix.apache.org/