# Joining two ResultSets from HBase in Java?

Tags: java, join, hbase

Is it possible to join two or more resultsets which are retrieved from hbase in java?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to join JDBC result sets.

However you can get their results and manually combine them if they are compatible. (if they are of the same entity).

EDIT :

If you simply need to combine two lists of the same type you can do

```
list1.addAll(list2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
What do you mean by manually? Assume i have two FilterLists that have returned two ResuktSets, How can i manually combine them?

Comment: You mean if you already have the results wrapped in a list of java objects?

Comment: Yes, but two separate lists, now i need to make them one.